# "unknown encoding name" when trying to install Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to install Ruby on Rails, but when I want to use Ruby, install bundle, or create a Rails app, I get this error:

```
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/win32/registry.rb:71:in `find': unknown encoding name - CP720 (ArgumentError)
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/win32/registry.rb:71:in `<module:Win32>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/win32/registry.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from dk.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Very glad that you decided to try Ruby and Rails.

Long story short, you're on Windows and there's a lot of caveats to get the Ruby on Rails stack running on this OS. I think you probably tried to install Ruby just by itself... Could you please try removing that and installing the bundle from http://railsinstaller.org/en instead? It will save you a lot of headaches like these in the long run. I've used it and it's a very well thought out package.

Let me know how it works out for you, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

this is because of the default code page of your command terminal.
use the below command to change the code page to Windows-1252 and you will not longer get that error

```
chcp 1252
```